# Maintaining state of the application using only static variables and static methods in class

Tags: java, oop, object, static

I am currently maintaining the application state using a class as below. It has only static variables and static methods

```
public class MyAppSession{

private MyAppSession(){ // private constructor}

private static UserProfile userProfile;
private static Enum appsessionMode;
private static List<UserProfile> guests ;
private static String host ;

public static UserProfile getUserProfile() {
    return userProfile;
}
public static void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
    MyAppSession.userProfile = userProfile;
}
public static Enum getAppsessionMode() {
    return appsessionMode;
}
public static void setAppsessionMode(Enum appsessionMode) {
    MyAppSession.appsessionMode = appsessionMode;
}

...... other getters and setters
```

I am maintaining the session of my application using these static methods and variables. In my application i am using this **class in numerous classes** to identify the state of my application and handle business logic. I will also be updating the session based on the users actions.

During my code review meeting i was asked to remove static, make it a singleton, and get the instance of this object in all dependent classes.

Now on the evil side of static, i know its difficult to mock these. and different memory allocation for static variables which are not freed.

**I want to understand what is the best way to handle such scenarios? is really static overkill for above scenario?**

Comment: Why don't you use a Singleton class?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is open for a discussion, and depends on each one's own taste, I would say that the way to go is with a **Dependency Container**. It makes testing a lot easier, and is considered as a best practice. Dependency Container follows great principles of good programming, and is an implementation of Inversion of Control (IoC), in which the control of the dependencies is inverted from one being called to one calling.

**[Singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern)** is considered as an anti pattern, for some regards. It actually pollutes the global scope. I once had the same conflict with using the language built-in **static** identifier, and have heard something that has changed my mind - do NOT use it. You can do everything without *static* identifier, and do it better. Only when you have full grasp of it - you may use it, sparsely.

One caveat: you maybe not use Dependency Container if you plan on a simple project. You can use Singleton, Registry, Multiton or even static. But those can become a serious drawback on large systems, as they are anti-patterns. By the way, your static implementation is actually an example of some kind of a Singleton.

Comment: but do you think using static methods and static variable is an overkill and not a practice to be followed here. atleast for my example

Comment: @PunithRaj, yes. You better leave the static identifier and adopt better infrastructures. Please look at the edited answer.

Comment: exactly, it may NOT be returning an instance of this object, but there exist only one instance as it has PRIVATE constructor and all variables are static.

Comment: @PunithRaj, That's right. You could use the [Null Object Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) to overcome this case.